# Issue with modulo.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In the proof of the theorem of inverse modulo. I encountered this problem and unable to comprehend it.

```
sa + tm ≅ 1 (mod m)
```

Then why it is equal to

```
sa ≡ 1 (mod m)
```

Comment: Because $m \equiv 0 \pmod m$.

Comment: $\,\color{#c00}{m\equiv 0}\Rightarrow t\cdot\color{#c00}m\equiv t\cdot \color{#c00}0\equiv 0\,$ by the linked [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). so $\, sa + tm \equiv sa + 0\equiv sa\,$ by the linked [Congruence Sum Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Answer (score 0):

$\equiv$ is a congruence relation and $m \equiv 0 \pmod m$, so $$sa + tm \equiv sa + t\cdot 0 \equiv sa \pmod m.$$

Comment: I do know that `m ≡ 0 (mod m)` but I want to know that what is the rule through which we can replace m by 0 in the congruence `sa + tm ≡ 1 (mod m)`?

Comment: @AliHusnain $m \equiv 0 \!\pmod{m}$ implies $tm \equiv 0 \!\pmod{m}$, and then add $sa$ on both sides to get $1 \equiv sa+tm \equiv sa+0 = sa \!\pmod{m}$. More generally, if $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$, then $f(a) \equiv f(b) \pmod{n}$ for any polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: @AliHusnain These are immediate consequences of the basic rules of congruence arithmetic (sum & product rules) = see the linked dupe for their proofs.